# Replace data from XML file after it is moved in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, string

I am developing an upload system when a user uploads XML files, then certain data from that XML file will copied into a SQL Server database.

My question is: can we copy a tag name (`ABC_1234_1_121`) and change its format into something like this (`[1234] 1 ABC 121`) and save that into the table in the database? Is it possible doing this? I need anyone help on this.

This is the example of XML files which will be uploaded into the server.

```
<ABC_1234_1_121>
<OTHER_TAGS>
..
</OTHER_TAGS>
</ABC_1234_1_121>
```

As you can see, the (`ABC_1234_1_121`) is from the <`tag`> of file xml above. I wanted to change the format to `[1234] 1 ABC 121` when I extract the `tag` to SQL Server database. But I do not know if this is possible to be done.

Comment: What are the rules for getting from `ABC_1234_1_121` to `[1234] 1 ABC 121` ?? If you can **clearly** and **unambiguously** describe the rules - then you can create some code to do it for you.

Comment: @marc_s I've edited my post. Can you refer to it again? Thank you

Comment: You're still absolutely **not** explaining how to do that conversion - how are you converting from `ABC_1234_1_121` to `[1234] 1 ABC 121`? What are the rules? You need to be able to **very precisely** describe each step and each scenario - otherwise, you cannot possibly turn this into code ....